# Best Web Crawler - for content extraction required

Tags: web-crawler

Structured web crawler solution to obtain content for a particular website like ebay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30 Digits has an excellent [Web Extractor](http://www.30digits.com/web-extractor/) for pulling very specific data from specified sections of websites.  It isn't open source, but they have different models depending on your size and use.

Answer (score 2):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is very good. And it supports Javascript pretty well.